# Assigning a Windows drive letter to a removable media brings a "Specified file cannot be found" error

Tags: windows, sd-card, drive-letter

I seem to be the only one over the planet to get this problem, as I spent 1,5 hours to find a solution and I couldn't even find a question...

One of my Sandisk SD Card has a strange behaviour. It's used in my Nikon camera. It works there flawlessly.

However when I insert it to a SD Card reader (tried three computers with different reader manufacturers) the drive letter disappears from Windows Explorer. I then look for it the Drive manager: it's recognized (size and name) but with no drive letter.

So now I try to assign a drive letter, I click... and I get the following error message: "The specified file cannot be found" (sorry , translated from french). Same on the three Windows computers.

[image: SD card recognized without drive letter]

Using Recuva I could get the files back from the card, no problem. It's just a problem of assigning a drive letter I guess.

Any clue on what's going on? I may be an experienced Windows power user, but that one got me stuck... Thank you.

Comment: This isn’t a unique problem.  Have you tried any of [these](https://superuser.com/questions/421749/windows-7-will-not-automount-assign-a-letter-a-flash-drive-behaves-really-str?rq=1) solutions?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/509992/unable-to-format-disk-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified) might also be a solution

Comment: Oh, man, @Ramhound, you are right, I'm not alone! Honestly, I searched everything, but it looks like the french message did not translate in what I was looking for... Unfortunately, all these solutions have already been tried. I can use my SD card on the camera and on Ubuntu, it's just Windows having trouble. I gave up and bought a new one. I'll keep this one for Ubuntu boot disk :)

Comment: So you have reformatted the card?